# SQL Reporting Service - Data Model

Tags: sql-server-2005, models, relationship

I create a data model that would replace two cut down tables.  With these two table I placed a Many to One relationships.

When I create reports that just uses a single table (This is the Destination table, within Data source views relationship) its missing records that should be displayed.  The records that do not display are records that do no have a linked record in the other table.

Help

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to create a query or a view that includes an outer join. Search your docs for `OUTER JOIN`. That should take you where you need to be. Topics should include `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, and `FULL` outer joins.